# Twitter API date created_at and conversion to local time doesn't add up

Tags: twitter

Pulling in tweets, the created_at time stamp is as follows:

> [created_at] => Sat Feb 21 17:00:26 +0000 2015

Looking at the actual tweet (on twitter), the tweet is date stamped as

> 9:00 AM - 21 Feb 2015

I'm in eastern timezone so the offset is -5 hours.

17:00 minus 5 hours is 12:00, not 9:00. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery solved, unless you are logged into Twitter, the default timezone must be Pacific. Once logged in tweets are timestamped with what ever timezone you have set. I am now logged in and the tweet shows 12pm.